# Prompt for Web Page by navigating to it with WebBrowser Control, using PowerShell?

Tags: winforms, powershell, webbrowser-control, prompt

Would it be possible to create a Web Browser control on a basic Windows Form, and display it, using Powershell?

I'd like to use a script to generate a form that contains a Web Browser control, with an address bar that can let a user navigate to the address they need, and a "Select" button at the bottom that lets the user close the form and as it's closing, the script saves the URL into a file on the local disk so the program calling this script can read that file as an 'Output'.

My end goal here is I want to be able to use a powershell script to "Prompt" someone to navigate to a web page and select it, so that I can capture the URL they're going to.

**Is there a simple way to do this** (?), or do I need to spend some serious time learning about how to generate WinForms in Powershell using lines of code and then open it?

I was hoping there was an example of this already done either on this site or somewhere else but haven't been able to find anything yet.

I don't have a ton of experience with powershell, so I haven't been able to try to do this on my own yet. I mostly work with VB.NET, and I'm trying to avoid having to create the form in a DLL and then reference it from powershell, which is something that would technically display the results I want but wouldn't be feasible for what I need this for.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly what you're trying to achieve, but you could probably use the Internet Explorer object. All Windows computer have it and it has all the basic functions: Navigate(), Visible, LocationUrl, LocationName, etc. Here's a basic example :

```
$InternetExplorer = New-Object -com InternetExplorer.Application
$InternetExplorer.Navigate("google.com")
$InternetExplorer.Visible = $True

# Wait for Internet Explorer to be ready
while($InternetExplorer.ReadyState){ Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 500 }

# Show Url / Name
$InternetExplorer.LocationUrl
$InternetExplorer.LocationName

$InternetExplorer.Quit()
```

If not, pretty much anything that can be done using the .Net Framework can be done in Powershell. That being said, you can build Windows Forms directly in Powershell, but I gotta admit it can be tedious. Here's a basic example:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
$Form = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.Text = "Sample Form"
$Label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$Label.Text = "This form is very simple."
$Label.AutoSize = $True
$Form.Controls.Add($Label)
$Form.ShowDialog()
```

Here's a more complete article if you want to get started:

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stephap/2012/04/23/building-forms-with-powershell-part-1-the-form/

Comment: The goal is that I can call a powershell script and direct someone to navigate, using a web browser control within it, to a specific web page, and then click a button once they've found that page, and the script records the page they selected / navigated to, as a sort of "prompt". I am working with a 3rd party application that can call a powershell script, so I want to build this in powershell so the 3rd party app I'm working with can use this script to "prompt" someone to navigate to an address and capture that address for use in that app / store that result in a field.